# Mysql increment

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have an auto-increment column in a table. When I delete a row I want to be able to re-use an ID but the system isn't doing that. Can you help me?

[image]

I want the system to use unused row IDs again.

Comment: The simple answer is: don't reuse id's.

Comment: It is not how auto_increment work

Comment: so what should i use ? i wanna auto increase + use the unsed rows

Comment: @KhalilHamdi What wasn't clear? You don't need it. Don't do it. It's a bad idea.

Comment: It is a really, really, REALLY, bad idea to reuse already used rows. As everyone has said. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

As most people pointed out in comments, it is bad idea. You would have to program your application's delete functionality in the way it either:

- marks row as deleted to be able to fill it in with new data
- force inserting data into empty slots

I am not sure what kind of performance impact it might have on updating indexes, usually primary key dictates the way rows are ordered on physical storage (MSSQL), however definitely this:

- brings extra complexity to your application
- you cannot guarantee that some other application / user doesn't delete and insert rows with disregard to your logic... unless you bring more complexity and expose everything via API
- you have to take care of all rows and their key reuse in other tables (considering that id will be a foreign key somewhere)
- in case of integration with other solutions it is nightmare for development of data consumers, as they cannot rely on any key to make sure you have row already or not (as bad as changing PKs every time you update row, seen that)

I bet others can come up with more reasons why this is bad idea. So in short. **It will make your application more complex for nothing.** So unless you have very good reason to do so - don't do it.

Incremental primary keys never go back, and never should. If you need some reusable number for any reason just make another column with reusable business key and create function to populate it.